# Fama MacBeth and Momentum Factor

Tags: panel-data, autocorrelation, factor-analysis, finance

I am working on a Fama MacBeth regression with excess returns on the LHS and Size, Value an Momentum factors on the RHS. In literature, the Momentum factor is often definded as the cumulative past 6 month returns of a certain equity.

The Fama Macbeth procedure accounts for cross-sectional correaltion of the residuals but it is not suitable to account for serial correlation. Cochrane (2009) argues that this is not a problem, because stock returns are likely to be uncorrelated over time.

How is it possible that many papers use Fama Macbeth regressions to estimate a Momentum factor which is actually based on serial correlation ?  It semms like a contradiction to me. Do I miss something?

Comment: I guess this is on-topic here, but you’ll have better luck on the Quant Finance Stack, maybe Economics.

Comment: Thank you, I´ll try there.